# Memory leak with alloc inside while loop iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have a memory leak in my iOS app, I am very new to memory management in IOS. Please suggest how to tackle the below problems.

The variable that is leaking is content. If i release the way I have shown in the code below (which is commented out currently), the object is still leaking. Also the while loop will always execute once.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                content  = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            }
        }
    }

    detailsArtViewController *det = [[detailsArtViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *decodeString = [self htmlEntityDecode:content];
    //[content release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Every alloc/init MUST be balanced with a release or autorelease somewhere. I don't see any release for your VC, nor any release of previous values of `content` if any.

So here are some problems with your code:

- **You don't have any protection in case your `while` loop execute more than once**. *(Actually you don't seem to have any protection for the case when it won't execute at all (SQL error or no result) either, but that's another matter)*. Meaning that in case your result is not what you expect, **you will get a leak**.
- You should thus **release the previous value of content before assigning it to a new value** in your loop, so that is case content is not nil memory will be balanced. *That's one reason using **properties** instead of ivars is more secure, by the way, see below.*
- Your **detailsArtViewController is never released** thus could be **the source of your leak** too *(by the way, class names should begin with uppercase letter. Following the naming conventions will help other understand your code better and save you a lot of trouble for understanding what symbols are, making sure KVC works, and much more, so you should adopt it the sooner possible too)*.

Multiple suggestions here, that I heavily recommand to follow:

- **[Read the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)** and **follow the memory mgmt policies**. The rules are really simple (every `alloc`/`copy`/`mutableCopy` must be balanced by a `release`/`autorelease`… and that's quite all you have to know, at least it is basically the most important rule).
- I strongly recommand to **[use properties instead of instance variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)** (if `content` is an ivar and not a local var in your case?). Thanks to Modern Runtime -- that is available since the beginning of iOS -- you don't need to create instance variables for your properties, the `@synthesize` directive will do it for you (in Modern Objective-C released with the last Xcode/LLVM compiler, you don't even need the `@synthesize` directive anyway). Using property quite everywhere instead of instance variables (using `self.content` instead of `content`) **will ensure that the setter of the property is called, thus the memory managment is done properly** releasing the previous value and retaining the new one (for `retain` properties), so you won't need to worry about releasing the old value, contrary to using the instance variable directly.
- You may **[use ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)** to avoid your leaks and **avoid having to do the `retain`/`release` dance yourself**. Of course I don't recommend `ARC` as "a way to avoid learning about memory mgmt": it is still really useful to understand how memory mgmt works, at least to avoid retain cycles and stuff like that, but it **will make things easier** by avoiding to bother about `retain`/`release` calls, so it is generally easier for beginners, even if I still recommend learning about memory mgmt to understand the logics and subtleties (that may also arise with ARC).

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to ARC and then you won't have to worry about this leak at all. It is great for beginners.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html